# Selecting specific columns with eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm on Rails 2.3.5 and trying to figure out the syntax for selecting on certain columns with eager loading. For example,

```
class Organizer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :organizer
 has_many :bookings
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :event
end
```

Let's say in OrganizersController show method, I wish to use eager loading to grab certain columns from Organizer, Event, and Booking models. I believe here's the code that grabs all the columns from all 3 models

```
Organizer.find(params[:id], :include => {:event => {:booking}})
```

But let's say that I only want to grab organizer.id, event.id, and booking.id, what's the syntax for doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in this [article](http://blog.codefront.net/2007/07/11/better-json-output-from-rails-with-the-jsonifier-plugin/).

Use :only like this, e.g.,

```
david.to_json(:include => { :posts => { 
                            :include => { :comments => { 
                                          :only => :body } }, 
                            :only => :title } })
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the right answer. `to_json` will give you the expected output but NOT will not be eager-loading as expected under the hood. Check the SQL logs.